# How to open vcxproj (visual c++ project) with visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, visual-c++-2008, visual-c++-2010

does anybody know how to open vcxproj in visual studio 2008. It seems this file was only opened by visual studio 2010 isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

You don't.  You'll need to create a Visual C++ 2008 project (.vcproj).

Visual C++ 2008 uses VCBuild; Visual C++ 2010 uses MSBuild.