# How to downgrade VC++ 2010 project to VC++ 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

This is a usual MFC project developed in VC++ 2010 but since my client does not have VC++ 2010, I need to downgrade to VC++ 2008. When I tried, I got "Cannot load the project due to a corrupt project file."

Is there any way to downgrade the project file?

**UPDATE:** As people suggested, I created new project in VC 2008 and started from there. It took an hour to make it runnable so I can't complain. But of course, it was not copy-and-paste easy. I had to copy all include directories and libraries correctly. And had to delete unnecessary code parts that do not exist in 2008. One thing I can't still figure out is an error in rc file

```
RC2176 : old DIB in res\MyApp.ico; pass it through SDKPAINT
```

It apparently can't recognize the icon format for some reason. For now, I commented out that icon part.

Comment: By 2010 project you mean a .vcxproj file? Those were a large change from the 2008 .proj files (using different build systems), so no, there's no downgrade path here. You'll have to create a project for VS2008. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621978/how-to-open-vcxproj-visual-c-project-with-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know of is to create a new VC++ 2008 project and copy all of your VC++ 2010 files into it. If you drag/drop from Windows Explorer into the Solution Explorer in VS, it will add them to your project and copy them to your project folder.

Comment: That is what I did. It took an hour so I can't complain. But of course, it was not copy-and-paste easy. I had to copy all include directories and libraries correctly. And had to delete unnecessary code parts that do not exist in 2008. One thing I can't still figure out is an error in rc file `RC2176 : old DIB in res\MyApp.ico; pass it through SDKPAINT` It apparently can't recognize the icon format. for some reason.